# Слова возымели действие... на меня? надо мной?

Tags: грамотная-речь, управление

> Наконец послышалось движение в закулисье и шёпот: «Занавес! Дайте
>   занавес!» **Эти слова возымели надо мной волшебное действие**. Я
>   пришла в себя и сдавленным голосом отправила Нину Александровну
>   поскорее подальше. А после того – уж всё как положено: заломила руки в
>   отчаянье...

Просто изъять "надо мной"?

В какой авторитетный источник можно заглянуть?

Где вообще сгруппированы глагольные управления, кто знает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возымели надо мной действие - разговорно-просторечное выражение, контаминация двух: возымели на меня действие и возымели надо мной власть (силу).

Возыметь действие - подействовать (на кого?) на меня.

Вероятно, лучше действительно изъять "надо мной".

В словаре управлений его и быть не может, там глаголы, а не сочетания, а это слитное сочетание. Во фразеологическом тоже нет сочетаемости,видимо, следует ориентироваться на здравый смысл.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо, не случайно в словарях нет вариантов управления: "слова возымели действие" - выражение самодостаточное. Это идиома со стандартным смыслом воплощения слов в *ожидаемое* от адресата поведение. Это *всегда* действие **на адресата**, поэтому литературные вольности с конкретизацией "на кого действие" разрушают идиому буквализацией смысла; вышедшее из употребления слово оказывается в роли обычного глагола и вряд ли украшает стиль, поскольку простое "подействовали" в случае *неожиданно* "волшебного" действия здесь убедительнее. Ну а вариант "возыметь действие над" - ещё и грамматическая ошибка. Я бы предложил воздержаться от "возымения":

> Эти слова **подействовали** на меня (самым) волшебным образом.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре глагольного управления, Розенталь, Д. Э. этого слова нет. А в других словарях нет никакого управления. Да и вряд ли можно возыметь действие над кем-либо. Можно, на мой взгляд,  на кого- что- либо.

Лучше так: Наконец послышалось движение в закулисье и шёпот: «Занавес! Дайте занавес!» Эти слова **возымели свое волшебное действие.** Я пришла в себя и сдавленным голосом отправила Нину Александровну поскорее подальше. А после того – уж всё как положено: заломила руки в отчаянье...

> Или: Наконец послышалось движение в закулисье и шёпот: «Занавес! Дайте занавес!» Эти слова **возымели  волшебное действие на меня.** Я пришла в себя и сдавленным голосом отправила Нину Александровну поскорее подальше. А после того – уж всё как положено: заломила руки в отчаянье...

Ср. примеры из корпуса:

> Такая позиция Иосифа Самуиловича, его приезд в Горький **на мою защиту возымели действие:** «оппозиционеры» вынуждены были воздержаться от дальнейших неблаговидных поступков… [Воспоминания о Шкловском (1996)].
>
> Последние слова возымели **действие и на путейца.** [Н. А. Островский. Как закалялась сталь (1930-1934)]
>
> Мои настояния **возымели действие,** и митрополит, хотя и неохотно, но согласился их уважить. [А. Ф. Кошко. Очерки уголовного мира царской России. 1 (1926)]
>
> Он прямо сказал о десяти тысячах российских военных пенсионеров, представляющих постоянную потенциальную угрозу независимости Эстонии. Его **доводы возымели действие**. Из скудного бюджета республики были выделены необходимые средства. [Виктор Левашов. Заговор патриота (2000)

Answer (score 1):

**Эти слова возымели надо мной волшебное действие.**

Возыметь **надо мной** действие, возыметь **надо мной** силу – это устойчивые выражения высокого стиля, например:

Без Святого Духа никто не может ни греха избежать, не сможет исполнить ни одну из Заповедей Божиих, ни отражать власть и силу, **какую возымели над ним демоны** (Симеон Новый Богослов).

В современных текстах подобные выражения приобретают оттенок иронии.

Comment: В приведённом примере действует предложная сочетаемость слова "власть" (власть над...; "сила" здесь употребляется в значении близкого синонима "власти"), из которой **не** следует возможность распространения предлога "над" на устойчивое сочетание "возыметь действие" (= подействовать как задумано, оказаться действенным, эффективным).